# SQL Query for Parent Child Data from two table

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have 2 table one table is Course Category and second is Course

In Course Category Table

Following data stores :

CategoryId | Name

1  | MCA

2 |  MBA

In Course Table

Following data stores :

Id | Name | CategoryId | ParentId

1  | Asp.Net  | 1  | 0

2  | C#     | 1  | 1

3  | Finance | 2 | 0

i want following output

Id | Name | Parent

1  | MCA | 0

2  | MBA | 0

3  | Asp.Net | 1

4  | C# | 3

5  | Finance  | 2

Whether i have to use nested query or should i relate two tables with foreign and primary keys or any mapping should be done.if not give me a solution to do this.

thanks in advance

Comment: How this parent count is calculated? Which is your database?

Comment: i want to show this data like MCA - > Asp.Net - > C# & MBA - > Finance

Answer (score 0):

```
select rownum as id, name, 0 as parent 
from Category 
union all 
select rownum, name, id 
from course
```

Comment: You should give a short explanation of what the query actually does.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you only have one level of children (no cases like parent<-child<-child)

```
select c.id, t.name, parent.name, c.name from course c
join category t on c.categoryId = t.id
left join (select c2.id, c2.name from course c2) parent on c.parentId = parent.id
```

This should give you something like

```
id |categoryname  |parentname  |coursename
1  |MCA           |null        |Asp.Net
2  |MCA           |Asp.Net     |C#
3  |MBA           |null        |Finance
```

This is not exactly your desired result but should do the trick to display what you want.